# Give hyperlink to tableview cell in iphone

Tags: objective-c, database, ipad, uitableview, hyperlink

I am having tableview.
In tableview cell I am having some links.
I want to open those links.
Problem is that the contents of tableview cell is coming from database.
So how can I give links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one solution for hyperlink in UITableViewCell. For this, create a custom cell which has `UITextView *txtView`. Then add this code in custom cell or change property in interface:

```
txtView.editable = NO;
txtView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Now use the custom cell in UITableView as link will be displayed as hyperlink which will be opened in Safari by double clicking them